# Inserting a sequence of numbers SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sequence, oracle-apex

I have a table 'Persons' which has a field 'ID' which is also a primary key. I tried this and I keep getting 'ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended'. I'm a beginner at this. I'm using apex.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE idNmbrs INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 100,
INSERT INTO Persons (ID) VALUES(idNmbrs.nextval);
```

Comment: You're missing a SEMI-COLON in the first statement of your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE SEQUENCE idNmbrs START WITH 100 INCREMENT BY 1;

INSERT INTO Persons (ID) VALUES(idNmbrs.nextval);
```

Comment: I get ORA-00911: invalid character when trying your code.

Comment: @user3415584 Try using single quotes for sequence name.